# Why does the array repeat the entered data from first to last

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with my code. I build this code but there is an issue that I cannot resolve myself. The code should work like this: When entering multiple data (name & email) the datas repeat from top to last.

For example I enter 3 names & emails one by one. I want an output of

- Fred fred@gmail.com
- George   george@gmail.com
- Laila    laila@gmail.com

But instead I get this results in my table:

- Fred fred@gmail.com
- Fred fred@gmail.com
- George   George@gmail.com
- Fred fred@gmail.com
- George   George@gmail.com
- Laila    laila@gmail.com

Comment: Did you look at my answer?

Comment: Hi yes xxxmatko I tried it and my initial data from other file disappeared.

Comment: What are your initial data? The problem is I do not see your any HTML in your post, so I am working with what I got.

Comment: The initial data is here please see. Starting here in this section
$.get("/files/data.txt", function (data) {

Comment: So i modified the answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `clearAndSave` method in the end when you call `$("#output").append(html);` you should call `$("#output").empty();` first to clear the previous results.

Change the method like this:

```
function clearAndSave() {
    //...
    $("#output").empty();  
    $("#output").append(html);  
}
```

If you want to presist your initial data, modify the `clearAndSave` method like this:

```
function clearAndSave() {
    // Clear fields
    nameInput.value = "";
    emailInput.value = "";
    var html = [];
    console.log(arraypeaople);
    for(i = 0; x <= arraypeaople.length - 1; i++){
        // Mark added rows to be able to remove them later
        html += "<tr class='added-row'>";
        html += "<td>" + arraypeaople[i].name + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + arraypeaople[i].email + "</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    // Remove just the added rows
    $("#output").find(".added-row").remove(); 
    $("#output").append(html);  
}
```